# Text content doesn't render in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to create a `linechart` with `tooltip` using [d3js](https://d3js.org/). 
When mouse is on the chart should appear a tooltip that show me the value in there point, all it work but the problem is that the `tooltipText` content doesn't render, even if I can see the it value in the console.

This is my code:

```
class Tooltip extends Component{

    render(){

        if(this.props.showTooltip){
            var focusXtranslate;
            var focusYtranslate;

            this.props.focusXtranslate === "" ?  focusXtranslate = 0 : focusXtranslate = this.props.focusXtranslate;
            this.props.focusYtranslate === "" ?  focusYtranslate = 0 : focusYtranslate = this.props.focusYtranslate;

            return(
                <g className="focus" transform={"translate(" + focusXtranslate + "," + focusYtranslate + ")"}>  
                    <line className={"x-hover-line hover-line"} x1={"910"} x2={"910"}></line>
                    <line className={"y-hover-line hover-line"} y1={"0"} y2={this.props.height -  focusYtranslate}></line>
                    <circle r={"7.5"}></circle>
                    <text id="tooltipText" x={"15"} dy={".31em"}>{this.props.focusValue}</text>
                </g>
            );
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

export default Tooltip;
```

Comment: Could you also provide those props that are passing in for this component?

Comment: The props passed changes dynamically, if you want to do some test you can set focusXTranslate as 444, focusYTranslate as 277, focusValue as 3656